# "NO REBIS AVAILABLE TO USE" even with Rebis in inventory

Tags: mods, the-witcher-3

I'm playing [Witcher 3 Enhanced Edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/witcher3/mods/3522) (version 4.93), and everything is going somewhat ok, except I'm having some problems getting alchemy to work. I have lot's of Rebis in my inventory, but when I try to craft potions (like Swallow) the game says "NO REBIS AVAILABLE TO USE" even though I have plenty in my inventory. What is going on here? Am I missing a distillation step or something?

[image: Inventory]

[image: Inventory]

[image: Inventory]

Comment: Why have you tagged this 'mods'? Do you have a mod installed that you think is causing this?

Comment: Also your screenshots seem to indicate that you have sources of rebis, but none of the ingredient itself. Have you tried crafting some?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I have a mod called "Enhanced Edition" installed. It makes significant changes to the alchemy system, among other changes. The link and version number is in the first sentence.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Can you explain a little bit? What is the difference between "source" and "ingredient"? As you can see in the second screenshot, I tried looking under "Substances: Primary" tab but I can't craft anything there either.

Comment: Assuming you have the recipe, rebis can be crafted from white gull, verbena, ergot seeds, allspice, and mistletoe. In your second screenshot you can see that you're missing ingredients to craft it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas if Rebis must be crafted, why do some plants say "Moderate source of Rebis"? Why can't I use those plants to craft Rebis? I already have whitegull in my inventory.

Comment: It's kind of like how you say that milk is a good source of calcium.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the comments, you don't actually have rebis, nor even the requirements to craft it. You have the recipe it seems, but not all the sources needed to get any, and all that's highlighted in the third screenshot is just a source, not the rebis itself:

> Assuming you have the recipe, rebis can be crafted from white gull, verbena, ergot seeds, allspice, and mistletoe. In your second screenshot you can see that you're missing ingredients to craft it. –
> Roddy of the Frozen Peas
> Aug 27 '20 at 11:35

> It's kind of like how you say that milk is a good source of calcium. –
> Roddy of the Frozen Peas
> Aug 28 '20 at 0:20